# Handling circular dependencies

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, requirejs, circular-dependency

I believe all four methods below will work, but it's unclear to me why anyone would ever use the first three simply because it's more code. However, the first (and most verbose) one is the one given in the RequireJS docs.

```
define "circular1", ["example1"], -> "circular1"
define "circular2", ["example2"], -> "circular2"
define "circular3", ["example3"], -> "circular3"
define "circular4", ["example4"], -> "circular4"

#1
define "example1", ["require", "circular1"], (require, circular) ->
  alert "example1 Before: " + circular
  circular = require "circular1"
  alert "example1 After: " + circular

#2
define "example2", ["require"], (require) ->
  alert "example2 Before: " + circular
  circular = require "circular2"
  alert "example2 After: " + circular

#3
define "example3", ["circular3"], (circular) ->
  alert "example3 Before: " + circular
  circular = require "circular3"
  alert "example3 After: " + circular

#4
define "example4", [], ->
  alert "example4 Before: " + circular
  circular = require "circular4"
  alert "example4 After: " + circular

require ["example1"], ->
require ["example2"], ->
require ["example3"], ->
require ["example4"], ->
```

- If `circularDependency` is going to be undefined until you do the explicit `require`, what's the point of bothering to include it in the definition (#1 & #3)?
- And if `require` is always globally available as the first script loaded, why ever pass it in? Is it just a matter of code clarity, viz. is it just to provide a neat snapshot of all of the dependencies at the top of the code (since you might not actually get around to the explicit `require` until much later? Or does it have some real impact on how RequireJS does optimization depending on whether or not it's included in the `define`?

I don't want to use any of these variations if it has a negative impact on my software just because it "works."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When RequireJS is loading each module as a separate file rather than bundling them all up, it makes a difference. Specifying the module in the list of dependencies tells RequireJS that it will need to load that module before it can call the module's function. Since `require` is synchronous and it won't try to load a script synchronously, if the script has not been loaded, it can't return you the module. Since `require` is supposed to resolve relative module IDs relative to the requiring module, you need to use the `require` it passes you. So:

1. The first way is correct. It tells RequireJS to load the module if it has not already been loaded. If `circular` is initially `undefined`, it can soon populate it afterwards with the other module.
2. The second way is **incorrect**. If `circular2` has not been loaded, the call to `require` will not work. It will resolve the module ID correctly, since it uses the `require` it was given.
3. The third way is correct *in this circumstance*, but if you passed it a relative module ID like `./circular3`, it **would not work**. It, too, tells RequireJS to load the module if it has not already been loaded, so you will not run into the problem in #2. The only difference is that it uses the global `require`, which lacks the context of the `require` passed to the factory function, so if you pass it a relative module ID like `./circular3`, it doesn't know what to resolve it relative to.
4. This way combines the incorrectness of #2 and #3. First of all, it cannot resolve relative module IDs correctly. Secondly, even if it could resolve relative IDs correctly, it still will not load modules if they have not already been loaded.

If you can guarantee that the `circularN` module will always be defined before an `exampleN` module requires it, then yes, it will work, but using ways #1 and #3 makes sure it will work even if that is not the case.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up figuring out the hard way when I tried this in jsFiddle that being in the same file (i.e context) was making things fail that should have worked. The key, as you said, is that you have to load the module before you can require it. I'm still curious as to why #3 works when the docs say "be sure to specify require as a dependency so the right context is used to look up a". That would seem to imply that #3 could lead to an incorrect context being used.

Comment: @neverfox: Now that I read that documentation snippet, I realize that there is actually an important thing I missed in my answer. I have updated my answer to cover it.

Comment: Very thorough answer. Thanks!